# Event queue not working properly winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, showdialog

Suppose a main form A and a modal dialog B.

I launch B from a thread (using invoke) as a modal dialog. The dialog is correctly shown and it is launched using ShowDialog(parent), where parent is form A.

When I close B, the main dialog A is not responding properly to some events, such as mouse clicks. This issue is only reproduced under the following circumstances:

- The code is compiled using .NET framework 1.1 profile
- The code is executed in a Windows 7 x64 machine

Once I close the dialog, the following symptoms occur:

- Form A does not respond to some mouse clicks, but respond to mouse moves (buttons are highlighted on mouse move).
- The main window close button is highlighted on mouse hover, also can be clicked, but the form is not closed.
- New modal dialogs are not modal anymore.
- Dialogs that have the property `StartPosition=CenterParent`, are not centered, they are shown in the top left corner on the screen.

I was unable to reproduce the problem in other machine. Also, If I compile the code using .NET 2.0 or higher, the problem is not reproduced.

Any suggestion to solve this issue? I need 1.1 for my application. Any call I could perform to restore the event queue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case when it doesn't working, did you check if dialog frees memory of OS, cause it could be that it remains and still "sucks" the mouse event from user.

Comment: It quacks heavily like a threading problem.  Not clear enough to pin-point the problem.

Comment: @Tigran: Sorry, I couldn't undestand your question. Could you please explain your question again? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I mean, could be that Dialog, for some reason, remains "alive" so mouse event pumping is recieved by him as it's modal, and not by parent form. Did you check, in case when error happens, if dialog actully destroy itself?

Comment: @Tigran: I'll double check, but I'm afraid that is not the case, because some events work, for example mouse move, and others (the buttons are highlighted when mouse move)... thanks anyway

Comment: @Hans Passant: I agree. It's a threading problem, but only reproduced in .NET 1.1. I'm sure that there is a workaround.

Comment: Am I to understand that you show this dialog from a background thread?  Can you change the dialog so that it is shown from the UI thread for form A?

Comment: If it is still "alive", it could be that you still have some event handlers registered on form b. I once had a memory leak that was caused by this (subscribing to events, but forgetting to unsubscribe once the form was closed). This meant the form was never collected.

Comment: Also can you confirm that the process is a 32-bit process, and not a 64-bit process?  All .Net 1.1 code should be 32-bit, but I've found something that would explain this if you had somehow managed to produce a 64-bit .Net 1.1 process, so I figured its worth checking! :-)

Comment: @Kragen: I can confirm that the process is a 32-bit process when I compile with .NET 1.1 (and also the problem is reproduced). If I compile with .NET 2.0 or higher, the process is a 64-bit process, and the problem is not reproduced.

Comment: @Mr Moose: Thanks, I'll check the that the dispose is removing all the resources of my form B.

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba: No probs. If you're interested, the following link is the walkthrough I used to discover my leak. Check out the paragraph from Figure 12 through Figure 15. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally it was a threading issue. I changed the calling code outside of a thread and it worked.

It is quite annoying because sometimes we need to show this dialog from a thread, but in the case of .NET 1.1 and x64 machines it seems to have some troubles with invokes and multi threading.

In any case, if the code is compiled with .NET 2.0 or higher (so works in real x64), the problem is gone.